# Speaker biographies/ Speakers' biographies/ Speakers' biography/ Speakers biographies

Tags: grammar

I just browsed a page about a talk on the National Gallery's website, which includes the biographies of some speakers:

https://www.nationalgallery.org.uk/whats-on/calendar/start-the-weekend-23-march-2018-1830

The biographical information is put under the title of 'Speaker biographies' ─ I was wondering actually if it can also be titled as the follows?

A) Speakers' biographies
B) Speakers' biography
C) Speakers biographies

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Speaker biographies* is an open compound word, i.e., not written together or with a hyphen.  The first element is singular because in compounds, English strongly disfavors pluralizing a [noun used attributively](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Nouns_used_attributively) such as *speaker*. A pie made from apples is an *apple pie* and a worker who washes windows is a *window washer* even though there are more than one apple or window involved. That eliminates your choice C.

*Speakers' Biographies* is not a compound, but a noun modified by a plural possessive, and would be a grammatically acceptable substitute.

*Speakers' Biography*, however, would only work if the speakers in question were, say, twins who were never apart. Otherwise, one would assume that plural speakers would have equally plural biographies.